# Custom button does not show title

Tags: swift, uibutton, subclass

I have customized an UIButton in Swift. But I cant get the title to display properly. This is my class :

```
import UIKit

final class CustomButton: UIButton {
    var cornerRs: Bool = false
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    convenience init(bordercolor : CGColor = UIColor.black.cgColor,
                     backGroundColor : UIColor = UIColor.black, foreGroundColor : UIColor = UIColor.black,borderThickness : CGFloat = 1,borderRadius:Bool = false,title : String, font : UIFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)) {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.cornerRs = borderRadius
        self.layer.borderWidth = borderThickness
        self.layer.borderColor = bordercolor
        self.setTitleColor(foreGroundColor, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        self.setTitle(title, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        self.backgroundColor = backGroundColor
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = (self.cornerRs) ? self.frame.size.height / 2.0 : 0
    }
}
```

This is my instantiation :

```
button = CustomButton(bordercolor: UIColor.blue.cgColor, backGroundColor: UIColor.blue, foreGroundColor: .white, borderThickness: 1, borderRadius: true, title: "Click here!", font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got it. You are supposed to call **super.layoutSubviews()** inside of your own layoutSubviews() overrode so inner views ( like the title label ) are displayed correctly.